# Auto logout of application

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an auto logout functionality. If the application is not used for a period of 1 hour i would want to automatically bring the user to the login screen. When the phone gets locked the thread which is monitoring if the application is in use does not seem to continue. My code is as below:

```
/**
 * This Deamon checks if the application is idle and 
 */
private class LogoutDeamon extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        while (!logoutDeamon) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Logout Counter:" + logoutConter);
                if (logoutConter <= 0) {
                    logoutDeamon = true;
                ApplicationManager.getInstance().setLoggedOut(true);
                   ApplicationManager.getInstance().Log(Level.INFO, "Auto Log out");
                   logout();
                } else {
                    decreamentCounter();
                }
                sleep(60000 * 1);
            } catch (ParserException ex) {
                Log(Level.ERROR, " Par. Ex. in Logout-Deamon:" + ex.getMessage());
                logout();

            } catch (ServerException ex) {
                Log(Level.ERROR, " Ser. Ex. in Logout-Deamon:" + ex.getErrorMessage());
                logout();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Log(Level.ERROR, "Int. Ex. in Logout-Deamon:" + ie.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log(Level.ERROR, "Erro in Logout-Deamon:" + ex.getMessage());
                logout();
            }
        }
    }

    private void logout(){
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent
                .setAction("com.package.ACTION_LOGOUT");
        applicationContext.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(applicationContext,
                Login.class);
        loginIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        applicationContext.startActivity(loginIntent);
    }

}
```

Am i missing out on something? Can someone kindly help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need a thread. Register the time in onPause. In onResume test if 1 hour has passed. If not, reset the timer.

Comment: The problem i have is that the time factor is not fixed. I get the logout period from the server. Hence i put the thread to sleep for a minute and decrement the timer. Would the thread get into a pause state if the phone gets locked?

Comment: Your thread will stop executing, when the device enters sleep mode. Anyway, when the device goes to sleep or when the user closes your application, onPause will be called. When the application starts again, onResume will be called. These two methods should be enough to implement your business logic - no thread counting time is required.

Comment: Thank you. Should this logic be implemented in all the activities? Since i have multiple activities in my application?

Comment: Yes, you should add the logic in all your activities. For example you could use a Singleton class that is accessed from all your activities. It could happen that onPause is called for one of your activities and then immediately afterwards onResume for another one of yours. This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Will try the same. Thank you.